# Using database value to show images

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

first of all, thanks for reading and sorry for the bad english.

So here is the issue I am creating a flask app. Pretty basic with a SQLAlchemy database connected to it.

so in my app.py here is what I have.

```
class Things(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = db.Column(db.String(100))
    company = db.Column(db.String(50))
    role = db.Column(db.String(100))
    mbegin = db.Column(db.Integer)
    ybegin = db.Column(db.Integer)
    mend = db.Column(db.Integer)
    dend = db.Column(db.Integer)
    comment = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    logo = db.Column(db.String(50))



@app.route('/')

def index():
    things_experience = Things.query.filter_by(type="Experience")
    things_academic = Things.query.filter_by(type="Academic")
    print(things_experience)
    return render_template('index.html', things_experience = things_experience, things_academic=things_academic)
```

In my index.html here is what I have :

```
<div class="row rounded" style="height:200px; color:#D8D8D8 ;background-color: #4D5051; margin:1.5%;">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class = "row" >
            <h3 class = "col">{{things.company}}</h3>
            <h3 class="col">{{things.role}}</h3>
            <h4 class = "col">{{things.mbegin}}/{{things.ybegin}} - {{things.mend}}/{{things.dend}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="{{ things_experience[0] }}" class="row">
          <p class="col-sm-6"> </p>
          <p class = "col-md-8" style="text-align:Left">{{things.comment}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="{{url_for('static', filename="{{things.logo}}")}}" class="img-fluid" alt='{{things.company}}'>
        <p>{{things.logo}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

don't ask me why the filename="{{things.logo}} doesn't work although, when I look in the static folder there is {{things.logo}}. The idea was to store the name of the image in the static folder inside the database's column logo. I don't know how to store images in a database so I came up with this idea (not so clever it seems...). Worst in the

{{things.logo}}

it prints me the correct value. So I am a bit lost on what is not working maybe there is something of a value({{things.logo}}) that exists ?? And that I should be using ?

If any of you have an idea on how to solve this I would be sooooo grateful :) !!!

Thanks in advance and have a great day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the syntax you're looking for is:

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename=things.logo)}}" >
```

You don't need the double braces around `things.logo` within the `url_for` call because `filename` is an argument, so accepts a variable name alone.

Comment: Ohhh Thank you so much !!! 

I was tearing my hair off !! I didn't know that filename was an argument itself.